# When to use [L] flag in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can someone give me an example when to use [L] flag? I'm learning about mod_rewrite moudle in .htaccess file and can't find out when to this flag.

Answer (score 3):

The `L` flag simply means to stop applying any rules that follow. Given the same URL, `http://example.com/foo/bar?q=blah`, and given the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^foo - 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.php?z=$1
```

The first rule gets applied and the URI gets passed through unchanged (via the `-` target). The rewrite engine then processes the next rule, and the URI gets rewritten to `/bar.php?z=foo/bar`. What happens when you add an `L` to the end:

```
RewriteRule ^foo - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.php?z=$1
```

The URL `http://example.com/foo/bar` gets passed through untouched from the first rule, then **stops** because of the `L` flag. If the URL is `http://example.com/something/else` then the first rule doesn't match and the second rule gets applied, rewriting the URI to: `/bar.php?z=something/else`

Note that since the rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing, the `L` flag will *not* prevent the looping, only any further rules from getting applied in the current iteration.

Comment: Can i use END flag inseated of L?

Comment: It relates to the global apache configuration. If you use `[L]` in httpd.conf then there still is a chance to apply some rules in .htaccess. But if you use `[END]` the game is over and .htaccess can not add anything

Comment: @khoibn **END** flag is available since apache 2.4 , The main diffrence between those 2 flags is that **END** ends the rewriting process immedeatly, while the **L** ends the rule proccessing ,it works like a continue loop.

Comment: L stops till where? Till next RewriteCond or RewriteRule or all subsequent rules?